# Converting a jQuery object to a plain object

Tags: jquery

Does jQuery provide a way to convert a selected element that is a jQuery object to a plain object, for example if you wanted to just perform basic javascript actions on the object without using jQuery after the element has bee initially selected?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

if you simply do:

```
$('div').get()
```

you will get a normal JS array of all the objects that jQuery selected.

```
$('div').get(0)
or
$('div')[0]
```

will give you the first item selected.

Comment: [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) | [Official FAQ](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/) -- The FAQ says `.get()` is slower than using array notation.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
jq_object.get(0);
```